# What's the difference between black currants and red currants?

Tags: fruit

I've noticed different stores carrying "currants" where some are red and others are black. What's the difference? Do they go by any other names?

For putting in cereal and making museli does anyone recommend one over the other?

Comment: There are also white currants, though they seem to be a bit harder to find.

Answer (score 3):

[Blackcurrants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackcurrant) and [redcurrants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redcurrant) are simply subspecies of the same berry-producing shrub.  Besides their color, they differ only slightly in flavor; red are somewhat more tart than black.  For most purposes, such as in jams or baking, they're basically interchangeable.  When dried they're also easily substituted for raisins or sultanas.

There's really no basis for recommending one over the other beyond personal preference.  For your cereal, museli, granola, whatever, try both and see what you like.

Comment: I just want to add one thing. Most "currants" sold in the US are actually raisins.

Comment: Strange, I find that there is a large taste difference between red and black currants. It is hard to quantify, but I'd say it is large like the difference between peach and apricot, not small like the difference between roma tomato and cherry tomato. Biologically, I think you are right, and it is certainly up to taste to choose one or the other.

Comment: @rumtscho Maybe the flavor difference has to do with freshness? Here in the US, blackcurrant production is restricted, so I've personally only had them dried or in jams, where I'd imagine you lose a lot of the distinction.  From what I can tell, they're also very close in flavor to local cousins like gooseberry (which as I understand is actually a separate variety from the European gooseberry).